# How to access MySQL database when given localhost access?

Tags: mysql, database, connection, localhost

I Googled this topic, and could not find an answer.

I am working on a site for someone and I need access to their MySQL database. They only gave me localhost access and the username and password.

How do I connect to the database through a tool like Dbninja?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't, you can try to use ssh port forwarding or a vpn connection.

Comment: You'll need to either remote into their db server using a tool like `ssh` or you'll need to reference the db server in a way that it can be found on the network, eg. ip address. Either way, you'll need to know the name or ip address of the db server, not `localhost`.

Comment: I've got the IP address of localhost, and I used the mysql port (3306). I could be using the wrong port. I used the IP in dbninja with no luck.

Comment: I attempted to connect to the database and I was unable to connect. It tried to download a file to my computer which had the following info inside: `M
5.5.21-55√ËIfBSZKHgMˇ˜¿Ä,3YIAI+;(SLamysql_native_password!ˇÑ#08S01Got packets out of order`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *ssh port forwarding* to map a local port to a port on their server.

Here's a short article that gives an introduction to how to do this:

http://onlamp.com/onlamp/excerpt/ssh_11/index3.html

Here's an article on how to do it if you use the terminal program *putty* on windows:

http://katsande.com/ssh-port-forwarding-for-mysql-using-putty

Basically, you ssh to the remote machine and then 'map' a port on that machine to a port on your local machine. Then you can connect your db program to the local port and it will be as if you were connecting to the remote machine from localhost.

Comment: Is it possible to ssh to the remote machine if I'm on a shared hosting plan? I also don't have root access to the server. I only have access to a specific directory (the directory for the site). I don't even have cPanel access. Is any of this possible? 

If none of this is possible for me to do, what should I ask the person who owns the server to set up for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure? by default MySQL supports localhost with full admin privledges if you login with root and no password. Are you running Win/Linux and did you install the binary/source version of MySQL?

Someone may have played around with your MySQL table which contains the details of all user accounts and rights, etc, so try giving it a fresh install. If not, checkout Ryan's article on MySQL permissions at http://www.devarticles.com/art/1/134. It contains everything you need to know to setup MySQL users

Comment: Where would I go to log in via localhost? They didn't give me cPanel access so I don't have any tools like phpmyadmin. Is there any way I can install phpmyadmin myself?